# normalizing a matrix by elements of another array?

Tags: python, list, matrix

I want to write Python code which does the problem mentioned below.

I have a a list of lists:

```
A = [[10, 20, 30], [15, 30, 25], [12, 30, 6]]
```

And I have a list of numbers:

```
B = [2, 5, 6]
```

I would like to iterate over the list B and divide each row of list A by elements from B.
for example:

```
[10, 20, 30] / B[1]
[15, 30, 25] / B[2]
[12, 30, 6] / B[3]
```

and get output like:

```
output = [[5, 10, 15], [3, 6, 5], [2, 5, 1]]
```

I don't know if use for loops would be a good idea to do this or no? as I could not get the correct result.

Any idea to figure out the solution?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

In Numpy you can do it as simple as following:

```
A/B[:, None]
```

Demo:

```
In [60]: A
Out[60]: 
array([[10, 20, 30],
       [15, 30, 25],
       [12, 30,  6]])

In [61]: B
Out[61]: array([2, 5, 6])

In [63]: A/B[:, None]
Out[63]: 
array([[  5.,  10.,  15.],
       [  3.,   6.,   5.],
       [  2.,   5.,   1.]])
```

Comment: @yas.f If it works, you can tell this to community by accepting the answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple nested list-comprehension:

```
>>> A = [[10, 20, 30], [15, 30, 25], [12, 30, 6]]
>>> B = [2, 5, 6]
>>> [[e / b for e in a] for a,b in zip(A,B)]
[[5.0, 10.0, 15.0], [3.0, 6.0, 5.0], [2.0, 5.0, 1.0]]
>>>
```